# Market Maker Dynamics and RFQ

Tags: fixed-income, algorithmic-trading, market-making

In the fixed income space, market makers, such as banks, often utilize platforms like TradeWeb. I'm seeking a clearer understanding of the workflow involved in this process.

From my current understanding, the process unfolds as follows: Suppose Bank A intends to sell one of its 2-year Treasury bonds. Bank A contacts TradeWeb, providing details like maturity, coupon of the bond, and the desired quantity. TradeWeb then relays this information to a pool of market makers, including banks and hedge funds. These market makers submit bids to TradeWeb, and the platform forwards these bids to Bank A, who ultimately selects the most favorable bid. Is this a correct representation?

Now, I have several specific questions:

**Selection of Market Maker Pool:** Is the pool of market makers chosen by Bank A, or does TradeWeb curate the pool?

**Bid Visibility:** Can every market maker in the pool see each other's bids, or is this information confidential?

**Bidding Algorithms:** What algorithms are commonly used by market makers to generate competitive bids? Do market makers typically price the asset based on its characteristics (coupon, maturity) and provide a bid slightly below that price?

Additionally, I'm eager to delve deeper into the intricacies of this process. Are there any recommended books or resources that provide a detailed explanation of fixed income trading, specifically focusing on the interaction between banks, platforms like TradeWeb, and market makers?

Thank you for any insights or resources you can provide!